# Golang most efficient way to invoke method`s together

Tags: go

im looking for the most efficient way to invoke couple of method 
together.

Basically what im trying  to to is invoke those method together and if something went wrong return error else   return the struct Type.

This code is working but i can't get the struct type or error and im not sure if its the correct way.

```
go func()(struct,err) {
        struct,err= sm.MethodA()//return struct type or error
         err = sm.MethodB()//return error or nill
return struct,err
    }()
```

Comment: The correct way is to return two values

Comment: For those downvoting, at the very least provide some feedback so the OP knows what to fix in their question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Go, it's idiomatic to return the two values and check for nil against the error

For example:

```
func myFunc(sm SomeStruct) (MyStruct, error) {
  s, err := sm.MethodA()
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  if err := sm.MethodB(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  return s, nil 
}
```

One thing to note, is that you're running your function in a `goroutine`. Any return value inside that goroutine won't be returned to your main goroutine.

In order to get the return values for that go routine you must use channels that will wait for the values.

In your case

```
errChan := make(chan error)
retChan := make(chan SomeStructType)

go func() {
    myVal, err := sm.MethodA()
    if err != nil {
        errChan <- err
        return
    }

    if err := sm.MethodB(); err != nil {
        errChan <- err
        return
    }

    retChan <- myVal
}()

select {
case err := <-errChan:
    fmt.Println(err)
case val := <-retChan:
    fmt.Printf("My value: %v\n", val)
}
```

You can mess around with it here to make more sense out of it:

http://play.golang.org/p/TtfFIZerhk

Comment: I wrote i complete rest api with Gorilla But for some reason i  couldn't figur out the Concurrency   part of go 
thanks allot

Comment: No problem, I'm not sure if you wanted to execute both MethodA and MethodB concurrently from each other. The code you provided will execute them serially in a different goroutine, if you want to execute them concurrently from each other I'd separate them in different goroutines.